# Rotating css 3d object doesn't work right

Tags: javascript, css, animation, 3d, rotation

First, look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/CJDeD/6/

```
         <div id="container">
            <figure id="box">
                <div id="back" class="side"></div>
                <div id="left" class="side"></div>
                <div id="right" class="side"></div>
                <div id="front" class="side"></div>
                <div id="bottom" class="side"></div>
            </figure>
        </div>
```

```css
        body{
            background-color: #000000;
        }

        #msgline{
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 0.5s 1s;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 1s;
        }

        h1{
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .side{
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #c8c8c8;
            color: darkgrey;
            border-color: #000000;
            border-radius: 20px;
            border-width: thin;
            border-style: solid;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #box{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -webkit-transform: rotateX(-20deg);
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform: rotateX(-20deg);
            transition: all 1s;
            -webkit-transition: all 1s;
        }

        #container{
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-left: 20%;
            -webkit-perspective: 800px;
            perspective: 800px;
            height: 200px;
            width: 400px;
        }

        #bottom{
            height: 200px;
            width: 400px;
            -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
            transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
        }

        #front{
            height: 200px;
            width: 400px;
            -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
            transform: translateZ(100px);
        }

        #back{
            height: 200px;
            width: 400px;
            -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px);
            transform: translateZ(-100px);
        }

        #left{
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
            transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
        }

        #right{
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(300px);
            transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(300px);
        }
```

```js
        function spinit(){
                var box=document.getElementById('box');
                box.style.transform=box.style.webkitTransform='rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(360deg)';
            }
        setTimeout(spinit(),1000)
```

It is meant to have a 3d rectangular prism with an open top. It does. I also want it to spin around 360 degrees. I included a little js function to do that, but it doesn't work. It works with any other value but not 360! I think that it is trying to simplify it by converting 360 to 0 because it is the same for most things, but not animations. There used to be another problem as well, but I figured it out and put an answer for it below. The animation works with other values (try changing the 360 to 180, for example), but not 360. I thought about trying 359, but it just rotated 1 degrees in the opposite direction instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I hate answering my own questions but I found out why the origin of the rotation was messed up. The box element should have had the following css properties applied to it:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

the new jsfiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/CJDeD/6/ However, the problem about the 360 degrees rotateing is still there, so please answer